# Not able to go back to original page from where React Router - Redirect was called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Problem: Currently app is redirecting user from  **PageA** to **ErrorPage** if some data is not found on **PageA** using react-router redirect. Now when the user is on **ErrorPage** and clicks on the browser back button. IT DOES NOT take back to **PageA**
Here is a code example
`
//PageA - this component is inside BrowserRouter

```
import React from 'react'

const PageA = () = {
    const data = null
    return (
        data ? (<PageAComponent />) : (
        <Redirect
                to={{
                        pathname: "/errorPage",
                        state: { referrer: 'PageA' }
                }}
        />
        )
    )
}
```

//ErrorPage

```
import React from 'react'

const ErrorPage = () = {
    return (
        <>.....something is displayed.....</>)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect), you need to set the [`push`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/push-bool) prop on `Redirect` to `true` to prevent it from replacing the current entry on the history stack when redirecting.